# Application of Maximum Likelihood estimation (MLE) to the Generalized Least Square (GLS) model

Tags: econometrics, regression, self-study, time-series, mle

I have the following regression

$$y = X\beta +u$$

where $y$ and $u$ are $(n\times 1)$ and $X$ is a fixed $(n \times k)$ matrix with full column rank and $\beta$ is an unknown $(k\times 1)$ vector of parameters.

$E(u)=0$ and $var(u)=\sigma^2 V$ with $(n\times n) $ symmetric and positive definite non-diagonal matrix $V$.

Let $\hat {\beta_{OLS}}= (X'X)^{-1} X'y$

Suppose $$u_t = \phi u_{t-1} +v_t $$ where $v_t$ is a white noise process with variance $\sigma_v^2$ and $\phi$ is an unknown parameter with $|\phi|<1$.

Describe how to get the feasible generalized least square (FGLS) estimator for $\beta$.

In the FGLS estimation procedure, we should use the maximized likelihood estimator $\hat {\phi_{MLE}}$, which should be obtained through the conditional log-likelihood  function set conditional on the first observation.

---

**What I did**

I obtain the variance-covariance matrix as follows:

[image]

Since $\phi$ is unknown, the matrix $V$ is also unknown. Therefore, we need to use FGLS as follows:

*Step 1:* Estimate the generalized regression $y=X\beta + u$ by OLS and obtain $\hat {u}$.

**Step 2:** Construct the auxiliary regression $\hat {u_t}= \phi \hat {u_{t-1}}+ v_t$ in order to obtain $\hat {\phi_{MLE}}$ and $\hat {v_{MLE}}$.

For that, I write down a likelihood function

$$v_t \sim N(0, \sigma_v^2)$$

$\hat {u_t} \sim N(0, \sigma_v^2)$

$I(\theta, u)=- \frac{n}{2} log(2\pi) - \frac{n}{2} log(\sigma_v^2) - \frac{n}{2\sigma_v^2} (\hat {u_t}- \phi \hat {u_{t-1}})'(\hat {u_t} - \phi \hat {u_{t-1}}) $

where $\theta = [\phi \sigma_v^2]$

FOC:

$$\frac{\partial I(\theta, u)}{\partial \phi} = 0$$

$$\hat {\phi_{MLE}} = (\hat {u_{t-1}}' \hat {u_{t-1}})\hat {u_{t-1}}' \hat {u_{t}}$$

*Step 3:*

By using $\hat {\phi_{MLE}}$ and $\hat {v_{MLE}}$, I will obtain the matrix $V$ and calculate $\hat {\beta_{FGLS}} = (X'V^{-1}X)^{-1}X'V^{-1}y$

---

I couldn't do the step 2. The question states the conditional log-likelihood function, however I cannot write down this log-likelihood function as conditional function to solve for $\hat {\phi_{MLE}}$  and  $\hat {v_{MLE}}$.

Please help me how to calculate the step 2. Thank you for your all kinds of helps and suggestions.

This is duplicate post.

Comment: See the "correcting for AR(1)" section in this. https://web.stanford.edu/class/stats191/notebooks/Correlated_errors.html. The two stage regression procedure described immediately below that should give you what you need.

Comment: Thank you @markleeds I took a look. However, on this page MLE is not applied. My actual questing is that.